# How to transfer one file to another location using java

Tags: java, file

I want to copy a file from location to another and convert it into bytes

So the test123.zip resides in C:/users/file and my destination C:/documents/shared/files

I have many files under this location C:/users/file but want to copy only test123.zip

I tried some thing like this

```java
File src = new File("C:/users/file");
File dest = new File("C:/documents/shared/files");
// Added new folder inside dest with name as file name
File newFile = new File(dest + File.Separator + fileName);

newFile.mkdirs();
```

Now I have C:/documents/shared/files/test123

```java
//Find path in the source folder
File copyFile = new File(src.getPath() + "/" + fileName);
Files.copy(Paths.get(copyFile.getPath()), 
           Paths.get(newFile.getPath()), 
           StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

Instead of copying it is replacing test123 folder but I want it to get added inside C:/documents/shared/files/test123 folder and then write the file into bytes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use a mixture of `java.io` and `java.nio`? Is there a special reason for it?

Comment: Is that the issue. Bit confused here

Comment: I don't think that's **the** issue, but it is definitely not a good practice.

Comment: It is the filename. I actually have it read like File file = new File("test123.zip")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use plain `java.nio`, maybe like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // directly create a path for the source and the destination
    Path sourceFile = Paths.get("C:/users/file/test123.zip");
    Path destinationFile = Paths.get("C:/documents/shared/files/test123.zip");
    // then simply copy the source file to the predefined destination
    Files.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
}
```

As an alternative, you could use `Path`s to represent folders and a simple `String` variable for the filename, e.g.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // define Paths for the source and destination folders
    Path sourceFolder = Paths.get("C:/users/file/");
    Path destinationFolder = Paths.get("C:/documents/shared/files/");
    // define a filename
    String filename = "test123.zip";
    // use predefined values to resolve absolute paths for the files
    Path sourceFile = sourceFolder.resolve(filename);
    Path destinationFile = destinationFolder.resolve(filename);
    // then simply copy the source file to the predefined destination
    Files.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to teach java folks (by way of an SO answer), completely unbidden, the anti-pattern of replacing an exception with useless error messages. The exception at least tells you _why_, 'Could not copy' is a frustratingly useless message to toss out there. The try/catch is additional code that makes the endproduct worse vs if you didn't have it. Remember, main __should__ be declared to `throws Exception`, generally!